# Command to get list of files with ".log" extension and "JB_" in name and "ERROR:" in the body of log file(not name of log file) in UNIX

Tags: unix, find

I tried this below command

```
ls -1 /fbrms01/dev/Logs/JB_*.log | find . -type f | xargs grep -l "ERROR:"  > /fbrms01/dev/Logs/text_JB.txt
```

for these below files

```
./JB_CreateFormat_2013.03.18_08.27.49.log
./JB_CreateFormat_2013.03.18_17.21.31.log
./JB_ExtReservationDetail_2013.03.15_13.06.26.log
./JB_Report_Master_2013.03.18_09.53.38.log
./StoredProcessServer/ApplyTemplate_2013.02.15.log
./StoredProcessServer/ApplyTemplate_2013.03.20.log
./StoredProcessServer/AuthView_2012.08.21.log
./StoredProcessServer/AuthView_2013.02.15.log
./StoredProcessServer/BookPace_2013.01.29.log
```

I'm getting all the files with `.log` and `ERROR:` in the output file but I want only files which starts with `JB_` and ending with `.log`.
Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /fbrms01/dev/Logs -type f -name 'JB_*.log' -exec grep -l "ERROR:" {} \; > /fbrms01/dev/Logs/text_JB.txt
```